# How can I add PlotLegend in SciDraw?

Tags: plotting, scidraw

```
Figure[
 FigurePanel[
  {
   FigGraphics[Plot[0.5, {x, 0, 10}, {PlotStyle -> Black}]];
   FigGraphics[Plot[1, {x, 0, 10}, {PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}}]];
   FigGraphics[Plot[2, {x, 0, 10}, {PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dotted}}]];
   },
  XPlotRange -> {0, 10},
  YPlotRange -> {0, 4}
  ],
 CanvasSize -> {4, 2.5}
 ]
```

[image: test]

How can I add something like this to the Figure? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Code firstly,don't just provide a screenshot,please.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in [`Legended`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html) and use [`LineLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html).

Comment: @rcollyer Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: @GrigoriSun `Legended` has the form `Legended[object, legend]`, and `Figure` returns a `Graphics` so it is perfect for this. Use `Legended[figure, LineLegend[...]]`.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks! Is there a more native way in scidraw that does the trick?

Comment: My use of SciDraw predates mma v9 (it was LevelScheme then), so legends weren't present at the language level except via the deprecated package. Therefor, I used the level scheme components to insert legends, see the plots in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4061.pdf). Since then, I don't know what has been added to SciDraw for legends, and I'd tend to use `Legended`.

Comment: SciDraw is a bit special.  It does not support the new legends, but you can still include them.  I would create a legend separately (e.g. a standalone `LineLegend`), then include it using `FigInset`.  Does this work for you?

Comment: @Szabolcs: `FigInset@LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"}]` gives an error. What exactly is your code?

Answer (score 2):

`FigInset` works with graphics (namely `_Graphics|_ContourGraphics|_DensityGraphics|_Image|_Graphics3D`); `LineLegend` is not a graphics object, rather a typeset object. Use `FigLabel` instead:

```
Figure[FigurePanel[{
  FigGraphics[Plot[0.5, {x, 0, 10}, {PlotStyle -> Black}]];
  FigGraphics[Plot[1, {x, 0, 10}, {PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}}]];
  FigGraphics[Plot[2, {x, 0, 10}, {PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dotted}}]];
  FigLabel[
    LineLegend[
      {{Red, Dashed}, Black},
      {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Mu]I\), \(B\)]\) = 5.0", 
       "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Mu]I\), \(B\)]\) = 10.0"}], 
      Point -> Scaled[{.05, .95}],
      TextOffset -> {-1, 1}];
}, XPlotRange -> {0, 10}, YPlotRange -> {0, 4}], 
CanvasSize -> {4, 2.5}]
```

[image: Example]