# Add a normal legend to an MMA plot in SciDraw

Tags: legending, scidraw

How can I add a legend to a standard Mathematica plot object that is embedded in a FigurePanel in SciDraw?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to use this in an iterated Multipanel.

I believe (from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141909/how-can-i-add-plotlegend-in-scidraw) question and answers to it) that the `Legend` objects are not Graphics objects and therefore can't be used in the `FigGraphics` environment of the `FigurePanel`, but is there some way to create a Graphics object from a normal legend that can?

More specifically: I want to be able to create plots using a simple function in the usual way as:

```
  
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2*x]}, {x, 0, 4}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red,Directive[Dashed,Red]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"label 1", "label 2"}], Scaled[{0.2, 0.2}]]]
```

But I'd like to be able to create a multipanel figure in which one iterates over arguments passed to the plotted function.

Here is a MWE of what I have so far, illustrating the plots I need.  How do I add legends to them in each panel?

```
(*Create a legend object*)
myLegend = Placed[LineLegend[{"label 1", "label 2"}], Scaled[{0.2, 0.2}]];

(*I will need different colored lines, so create two lists to iterate over*)
colorList = {Red, Blue, Black};
colorList2 = {Directive[Red, Dashed], Directive[Blue, Dashed], 
   Directive[Black, Dashed]};

(*Need to be able to create a multipanel with iterated function*)
Figure[
 Multipanel[
  FigurePanel[
   {
    FigGraphics
     [
     Plot
      [
      {
       f[x, PanelRowIndex, PanelColumnIndex],
       f[x, PanelColumnIndex, PanelRowIndex]
       },
      {x, 0, 1},
      PlotStyle -> {colorList[[PanelRowIndex]], 
        colorList2[[PanelRowIndex]]}
      ]
     ]
    },
   All,
   (* Axes and ticks *)
   YPlotRange -> {-0.1, 1.1},
   YTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, 0.25, 4]
   ],
  (* Geometry  *)
  Dimensions -> {3, 2},
  ],
 CanvasSize -> {9, 6}
 ]
```